# Oracle Analytics and Refreshing the Data Set

Tags: oracle

I am new to using analytics. I would like to know if when I create a new connection and a data set, how can I automatically refresh the information in my graphs? since I updated a data and it is not reflected in the graph ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create data flow and schedule it. So the dataset will be updated.
Please see the below pic:
Kindly let me know if you have further questions.

[image: Data Flow In Oracle Analytics]

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just what I needed! :)